# Spark Implicit $ for DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit-conversion

Where in the `sqlContext.implicits._` does it define the $"string" to represent a dataframe call to the parent dataframe's column? Specifically I was confused on seeing something like the following:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
df.where($"type".isin("type1","type2") and $"status".isin("completed","inprogress"))
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you see the [following link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.implicits$.html)

> class     SQLContext.implicits$.StringToColumn
>
> Converts $"col name" into an Column.

[Here is the link for latest version](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.StringToColumn.html).

Comment: And in consumable English, this means that, for instance in the OP's example, `$"status".isin("completed", "inprogress")` means that the column name `"status"` is converted / treated as an object itself, then within that object transformations or actions can be made.  In this case, only rows that have the column `"status"` containing either `"completed"` or `"inprogress"` will be kept.  Hope that helps!